# why don't I get any data back for `uspsData` when using the googlemaps address validation endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps

I'm using the python library for googles address validation endpoint.
previously when I was working on things I would get data for the uspsData key.
now when I make a call the only keys in that dict is `carrierRoute`.
But before it would contain a `standarizedAddress` field.

I have a small wrapper class for the endpoints i use

```
class Gmaps:
    ctype_map = {
        'street_number': 'line1', 'route': 'line1',
        'postal_code': 'zip_code', 'postal_code_suffix': 'zip_code',
        'locality': 'city', 'administrative_area_level_1': 'state',
        'country': 'country', 'subpremise': 'line2',
    }
    all_states  = {y for x in Address.state_map.items() for y in x}
    def __init__(self, raw=False):
        self.raw = raw
        self.gmaps = googlemaps.Client(creds['gmaps_key'])

    def validate(self, line1='', city='', state='', zip_code='', line2='', country='US', usps=False):
        if usps and country != 'US':
            raise Exception('USPS validation only works for US addresses')
        envelope_lines = [
            f'{line1} {line2}',
            f'{city}, {state} {zip_code}'
        ]
        try:
            result = self.gmaps.addressvalidation(envelope_lines, country, city, enableUspsCass=True)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

I recently switched accounts I'm using and im wondering if its somehow because I don't have the correct products enabled.
other than that the only thing I could think is that its been updated and changed somehow. I'm quite confused by this behavior right now.

[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/validateAddress#UspsAddress][1]

Answer (score 0):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294140306

it looks like this is a bug they are working on